# tidyverse: ANOVA for each level of a factor

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, anova

I want to perform ANOVA for each level of a factor. I can do this with `dplyr::do` but would like to have with `purrr` also. Any hint, please.

```
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- mtcars
df1$cyl  <- factor(df1$cyl)
df1$gear <- factor(df1$gear)

fm1 <-
  df1 %>%
  dplyr::group_by(gear) %>%
  dplyr::do(m1 = summary(aov(mpg ~ cyl, data = .)))

fm1$m1

> fm1$m1
[[1]]
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
cyl          2  69.03   34.52   4.596  0.033 *
Residuals   12  90.11    7.51                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

[[2]]
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
cyl          1  137.3   137.3   8.123 0.0172 *
Residuals   10  169.0    16.9                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

[[3]]
            Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
cyl          2  167.4   83.68   16.74 0.0564 .
Residuals    2   10.0    5.00                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

fm2 <-
  df1 %>%
  dplyr::group_by(gear) %>%
  tidyr::nest() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(m2 = purrr::map(.x = data, .f = ~ summary(aov(mpg ~ cyl, data = .)))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest()
```

Comment: Do you have what you want if you remove your final `unnest()` step?   Then `fm2$m2` would match `fm1$m1`.

Comment: Thanks @aosmith for useful comment. Would appreciate if you guide to how give automatic names to these components.

Comment: There's a straightforward way of doing this doesn't need pulling in the entire tidyverse, using a standard split-apply technique: `fm2 = lapply(split(df1, df1$gear), function(d){summary(aov(mpg~cyl, data=d))})`.

Comment: Off the top of my head you could set the names within `mutate()`.  Like `m2 = purrr::map(.x = data, .f = ~ summary(aov(mpg ~ cyl, data = .))) %>% setNames(gear)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a nested dataframe and then save all summaries in a new list column:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- mtcars

df_aov <- df1 %>%
  dplyr::group_by(gear) %>%
  tidyr::nest() %>%
  dplyr::mutate(.data = .,
                aov_results = data %>% purrr::map(.x = ., .f = ~ summary(aov(mpg ~ cyl, data = .))))

df_aov$aov_results[[1]]
#>             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)  
#> cyl          1  137.3   137.3   8.123 0.0172 *
#> Residuals   10  169.0    16.9                 
#> ---
#> Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
```

<sup>Created on 2018-10-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: If you're going to give "not a direct answer to your question" you may as well give the base R solution which is simply: `fm2 = lapply(split(mtcars, mtcars$gear), function(d){summary(aov(mpg~cyl, data=d))})`

Comment: I have modified my answer.